# jq command parses invalid JSON ( numerics splited with space )

Tags: json, stream, jq

i think it is invalid as JSON.
but jq command does not raise error and parse it.

What does mean that?

```
$ echo '1 2 3' | jq .
1
2
3
```

( `version : jq-1.5` )

Answer (score 2):

From the `jq` man page:

> by default, jq reads a stream of JSON entities (including numbers and other  literals)  from
>          stdin.  Whitespace is only needed to separate entities such as 1 and 2, and true and false.

In your example, jq parses `1`, which is a valid JSON entity by itself, and then proceeds to parse `2` and `3`. In other words: the jq command parses the input `1 2 3` because it happens to be valid JSON entities separated by whitespace.

If you use the `--slurp` option, which prints an array of all the input entities, you can see that it treats `1`, `2` and `3` as separate entities:

```
# separate entities:
$ echo '1 2 3' | jq --slurp
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]

# a single entity:
$ echo '"1 2 3"' | jq --slurp
[
  "1 2 3"
]
```

For comparison, the following inputs will fail to parse:

```
[1 2 3]
1, 2. 3
```

Comment: Thank you! i do not understand what is JSON entity. but i will try it.